# display Master-Detail relationship in JDL-studio

Tags: jhipster

I have generated two entities:

SaleOrder
SalesOrderItem

OrderItem is detail ， SaleOrder is master

I map them use JDL:

```
relationship OneToMany {
     SalesOrder{orderItems} to SalesOrderItem{salesOrder}
}
```

}

studio screen display UML，
[image]

Is this direction the opposite?

Object relationship is：
[image]

Indication by E-R ：

[image]

Comment: thinks you replay ，I mean：
The aggregation direction of UML is Incorrect ，SalesOder is A aggregateRoot is relationship soruce；

I am not sure if it is a bug；

Comment: this is a issue https://github.com/jhipster/jdl-studio/issues/117#issue-723286100
@Gaël Marziou

Answer (score 0):

Since "SaleOrder" is the Master, you better have its ID or OrderNo in SalesOrderItem
It's better if you map the relationship this way :

```
relationship OneToMany {
     SalesOrder to SalesOrderItem{orderNo}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply，I want to be clear the “OneToMany” relationship   is represented by uml aggregation or E-R connection？

Comment: this is a issue github.com/jhipster/jdl-studio/issues/117#issue-723286100 @SonOfHarpy